# Perl keyword say is not working in version 5.14.4

Tags: perl, version

My Perl version is 5.14.4, but the function `say` is not working. What might be wrong?

Comment: Add your code please.

Comment: `say` is not a keyword.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For backwards compatibility reasons, it's not available by default. You could use

```
CORE::say(...);          # Requires Perl 5.16.
```

but it's probably better to add one of the following:

```
use feature qw( say );   # Requires Perl 5.10.
use v5.10;               # All 5.10 features including "say".
use 5.010;               # Same as previous.
use v5.14;               # All 5.14 features including "say".
use 5.014;               # Same as previous.
```

This is [documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html).